# Certificate verify failed, using fresh Plesk installation

Tags: debian, php, ssl, certificate

I have a fresh installation of

- Debian 8.1
- Plesk 12

Plesk installed Postfix and Dovecot and added a default certificate for Postfix.

I'm running PHP 5.6 for my website. New in 5.6, PHP verifies certificates.

So I was suggested to get the default certificate by Plesk trusted by doing the following:

```
cp /etc/postfix/postfix_default.pem /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/postfix_default.crt
update-ca-certificates
```

Unfortunately I'm still getting this error:

> stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 5.
>   OpenSSL Error messages: error:0200100D:system library:fopen:Permission
>   denied error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib
>   error:0B06F002:x509 certificate routines:X509_load_cert_file:system
>   lib error:14090086:SSL
>   routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo chmod a+r /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/postfix_default.crt
```